# Returning a function with a callback inside

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

Heres my code. I basicly want to return the 'body' var in my getFollows function. Setting vars obviously dont work, no idea how to get the variable. I can't change getUserFollowedChannels because its a package, and I need to return it to the function directly because of meteor server->client stuff.

```
'twitch.getFollows'() {
    var followers = twitch.getUserFollowedChannels('atlatonin', function(err, body) {
        if (err) {
            return err;
        } else {
            console.log(body.follows[0].channel.display_name);
            return body.follows[0].channel.display_name;
        }
    });
    return followers;
},
```

Comment: Perhaps a dup of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Comment: Just an alias, basicly reads as 'twitch.getFollows': function() {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a callback function as below:

```
'twitch.getFollows': function(done) {
     twitch.getUserFollowedChannels('atlatonin', done);
 }
```

And invoke the function as below:

```
twitch.getFollows(function(err, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        //return err;
    } else {
        console.log(body.follows[0].channel.display_name);
        //return body.follows[0].channel.display_name;
    }
});
```